# Email TLS encryption - personal data

Tags: tls, email

I submitted some personal data to an organization through a HTTPS website but then they emailed it all back to me in a PDF. This included name, address and DOB. There was no end-to-end encryption on this email or PDF, but they claim as they are using "TLS encryption" for the email, it is secure. I am not so sure about this!

My Gmail inbox shows their message as "security: gray" and refers to [this page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6330403). I can see several mail servers listed in the "Received:" headers on their message.

I have read around about TLS email, but do not fully understand it.
Am I correct in thinking that, with TLS email, the encryption is applied between different email servers (and there may be many such "hops") rather than end-to-end encryption between the Gmail email server and the organization's email server? If it is indeed on a "hop-by-hop" basis, could each mail server in the chain read the message, potentially store it, and be a point where my data could get intercepted or compromised?

Comment: Indeed "Transport Layer Security" only protects the data during transport, and not during storage or processing on intermediate hops.

Comment: *"If it is indeed on a "hop-by-hop" basis, could each mail server in the chain read the message, potentially store it, and be a point where my data could get intercepted or compromised?"* - yes. Each MTA hop has access to the mail, can read it and can also modify it. TLS is only between MTA and not even this can be ensured by sender or recipient.

Comment: Oh crikey, thanks for the responses - surely they should not be emailing data in this way?

Comment: Certainly they shouldn't.  For true end-to-end email encryption, we have standards such as as PGP or S/MIME.